# How do I remove transient pixels from rendered image?

Tags: node-editor, blender-internal-render-engine, color

How to remove this semi-green pixels? I need exactly G = 255 color

[image]

I render this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9achR.jpg). And if you zoom in, you can see those pixels as shown above. 
My goal is to remove those transient pixels from it, so that this pic have only 4 exact colors. R = 255, G = 255, B 255 and Black.

Comment: I think you could do this in the compositing node editor: Feed the render output into a "seperate RGBA" node, then use that values as  inputs for colour ramp nodes (assuming the green values might have some small blue/red content you don't want) here you can set a color green for the higher values (and the background color for the lower ones)... Instead of the color ramps you could also consider use some mix nodes, depending on what exactly you are trying to do. Then finally you use a "combine RGBA" node to combine the color data and feed that into the output.

Comment: is there a simplier way to get rid of those unwanted pixels?

Comment: Those pixels represent the emission at the subpixel geometry level. Typically, you want and need that.

Comment: @troy_s have you heard about pixel-perfect?

Comment: That is pixel perfect. What you are discussing is a sampling issue.

Comment: @troy_s thanks for clarifying then, I guess

Comment: To get the unoccluded / without geometry value, which would effectively be the RGB emission at the subpixel level without the geometry, convert the alpha / RGB to unassociated via the node or a divide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved my problem by setting filter size to 0.00px

[image]